# Was the design of the Peacekeepers inspired by the Stormtrooper design?

Tags: star-wars, the-hunger-games, inspiration, stormtroopers, design

[image: Peacekeepers vs. Stormtroopers]

The Peacekeepers of *The Hunger Games* and the Stormtroopers of *Star Wars* have many similarities:

- Both wear almost entirely white full-body armor.
- Both see out of dark, face-obscuring black glass.
- Both are the faceless soldiers of tyrannical dictatorships.
- Both have rounded, head-encasing helmets.
- Both have "Wordotherword-er" names.

While *Star Wars* certainly didn't invent the concept of faceless soldiers, it *did* bring white and black armored faceless soldiers into pop-culture.

Has either Suzanne Collins or anyone associated with the films commented on the similarities?

Comment: Personally I always thought they looked more like Daft Punk.

Comment: "Stormtrooper" is a "Verbnouner" name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly, the Peacekeepers didn't always look quite so much like Stormtroopers. In the first film, their helmets didn't encase their whole heads nor have those one-way visors of black glass:

[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]

I found [an article](http://www.zimbio.com/Screen+News/articles/7TJSx1LPv_v/Check+Out+Changes+Made+Peacekeeper+Uniforms) with a statement from the designer, Trish Somerville, that she was "inspired by insects, particularly the praying mantis", but makes **no mention of the Star Wars Stormtroopers**. It is sourced to [this article](http://capitolcouture.pn/post/65379169338/exclusive-the-peacekeepers-uniforms-panems-new) and also backed up by [this interview](http://www.ew.com/article/2013/08/05/the-hunger-games-catching-fire-costume-qa-with-trish-summerville) (thanks @Richard for the find!), where Summerville says:

> I love the Peacekeepers that I did. I wanted to make them look a little more menacing, kind of insect-like. I draw a lot in my inspiration boards from different projects, a lot from nature, and animals, and insects. I just think that there’s so much there, in silhouettes and colors. The colors, they’re amazing, when you look in the insect world, and at in animals and nature. I wanted to make these Peacekeepers… after the first film, I felt like they needed to be bumped up a bit, because of what was going on in the second film with the rebellion that’s starting. I felt that we needed to show a transition, that the Capitol is stepping up its forces and making it much more intimidating and fearsome. So I went for this sort of spiny, praying mantis sort of look for them.

Comment: http://www.ew.com/article/2013/08/05/the-hunger-games-catching-fire-costume-qa-with-trish-summerville

Comment: Thanks @Richard! Added it to the answer, crediting you :-)